# Qt application with webview on mac os 10.10 giving "The certificate has expired" error

Tags: macos, qt, ssl, openssl, osx-yosemite

I'm using Qt 4.8.6, but this also happend on 4.8.5 on mac os 10.10. I've tested on 10.9 and 10.7 and I'm not getting this error, I've tried rebuilding the qt libs and ignoring ssl errors but it doesn't work properly, the website loads but I'm still getting SslHandshakeFailedError when using a QNetworkAccessManager.

I've also tried

```
QSslConfiguration sslConfig = QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration();
sslConfig.setProtocol( {various protocols...} );
QSslConfiguration::setDefaultConfiguration( sslConfig );
```

But it didn't help.

Comment: Did you check that your local time is correct?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yes I did, :)